# Why is the movie named "Hot Fuzz"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

["Hot Fuzz"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_fuzz) is a british comedy-action-thriller movie from 2007, "fuzz" being a [derogatory slang term for police](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_slang_terms_for_police_officers).

Is there any additional pun or play of words in the use of "Hot"? Or is it simply referring to the "hotness", the "awesomeness" of the police officer who plays the leading role?

For example, it would not have surprised me if "hot fuzz" were slang for a beverage or dish. But as far as my research shows, that is not the case.

Comment: _Fuzz_ also means "fluffy or frizzy hair"; maybe the play on words is about that.

Comment: I want to find a link between the film title and [Hot Fuss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Fuss) by the Killers, because it would be really apt. I can't though :(

Comment: I assumed it was a pun on "hot fudge", a popular ice cream topping (at least in the US).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No there isn't a particular BE term Hot-Fuzz. The makers of the film were parodying the way all Hollywood films show American police in a ridiculously high charged, high adrenalin overblown way while British police shows were always about a quiet, cerebral, upper-class detective.

So the term Hot-Fuzz links the *Hot* (=exciting action packed) with Fuzz (=British term for police). It's like having a show called "Librarian, camera, action"

But I suspect the Hot is really the high-performance over-achieving lead character.

Comment: +1: but isn't "Librarian, Camera, Action!" showing on Channel 5 over Christmas?

Comment: @TimLymington: Sssh!

Comment: @Tim, no you're thinking of "CSI-Ms marple"

Comment: Okay, it's a silent movie.

Comment: As I recall, the cop in *Hot Fuzz* is "hot" like *mustard* (keen, on the ball, effective). In spirit, at least - but since it's a comedy, he's actually about as effective as the Keystone Kops). Plus maybe a joke/poke at Michael Mann's 1995 cop/gangster movie *Heat*.

Comment: Conan the Librarian

Comment: I'd like to point out that "fuzz" is not exclusively Britslang; in fact, it seems to have originated in the US around 1929.  The origin seems to be uncertain.  When I was taking Spanish in high school, I noticed that _policía_ (police) is quite close to _pelusa_ (fuzz), but I think that's just an amusing coincidence.

Answer (score 4):

It's also a play on the album by The Killers "Hot Fuss", which was extremely popular in the UK.

Answer (score 4):

I mean, the movie came out in 2004, and so did the Killers album.

There's also a cameo of the Hot Fuss album in Hot Fuzz.

About halfway into the movie where Angel is in the shop, and the woman is like, "Found the killers yet?", there's a poster of the Killers album behind her.
This is about 1 hour 11 minutes into the movie.

Comment: "Hot Fuzz" debuted on February 14, 2007. "Hot Fuss" on June 7, 2004.

Answer (score 0):

[Hot fudge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_fudge#Hot_fudge) is a popular ice cream topping in the US, the key ingredient of a [hot fudge sundae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_fudge_sundae#Hot_fudge_sundae).  I'm in the US and from the first I heard of the movie, I assumed this was the pun.  But I'm not sure whether hot fudge exists under that name in the UK.

Comment: We have a hot fudge sundae, but it's not a term with any particular cultural resonance over here.

Answer (score -2):

Based on the context of the movie Hot would be applicable to mean stolen or illicit.

Comment: It could, but I'm not sure why it would be — there's no particular reason for it in the context of the film plot, surely?